# How to add a calculated column to rpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, dt, rpivottable

I have a time series (DataFrame) of six months (Jan to June) which I display in a Shiny App using rpivoTable package.

I need to add quarterly total to my data. i.e. (Q1Total and Q2Total should be calculated columns)

```
Jan Feb    Mar   Q1Total    Apr   May  Jun    Q2Total
-10   14   16     20        15    25  30       70
 13   -17  10      6        -2    -3   4      -1
```

The 2nd question is: How can I show the negative data in RED and Positive in Black in rpivotTable?

Thanks for helping.
Masoud Paydar

Comment: you should try to provide a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MLavoie, I am very new to StackOverFlow! I thought my question is general and clear about rpivotTable. However, I will write an example and post it again. By the way can we add totals to DT package in Shiny (Client side by using the HTML and JS)? Shall I post another question?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay ;). I'm the creator of the package (on top of the marvellous work of the creator of `pivottable.JS`).  Thanks for using `rpivotTable`.  `R` allows to add as many columns you want to your dataframe, including programmatically.  This is the intention of the package: use `R` for any manipulation & `rpivotTable` as UI.

Comment: Hello @Enzo thanks for the comment. Sure will do so.

Comment: @Enzo: Thanks for extraordinary work. we are truly thankful for all your work on rpivottable however when it comes to calculated field it seems to be a no workarround till the time. so e,g, if based on pivot i found a total of two columns and i would like to create one more column in pivot itself like (column 1* column2)/100. (do you think if this task is achievable)